# Python SQLITE3: 'AttributeError: 'ConexionDB' object has no attribute 'execute'

Tags: python, sqlite

I am trying to retrieve data from tables in SQLITE3 on Python. But I have received

MI CODIGO

```
from .conexion_db import ConexionDB


def crear_tabla():
    conexion = ConexionDB()

    sql = '''
  CREATE TABLE peliculas(
    id_pelicula INTEGER,
    nombre VARCHAR(255),
    duracion VARCHAR(10),
    genero VARCHAR(255),
    PRIMARY KEY (id_pelicula AUTOINCREMENT)
  )
  '''

    conexion.cursor.execute(sql)
    conexion.cerrar()


def borrar_tabla():
    conexion = ConexionDB()

    sql = 'DROP TABLE peliculas'

    conexion.cursor.execute(sql)
    conexion.cerrar()
```

Comment: What is `ConexionDB`?  Is that your own class wrapping SQLite3?

Comment: @TimRoberts it looks like someone created a wrapper around a database library to translate all the function calls to have names in their native language. Which is a spectacularly bad idea - and probably the reason that it has no `.execute()` method, but  a method named whatever they thought was a good translation of `.execute()`. (in case you wonder: no, English isn't my native language either, but I'm a developer, so I learned - the history of computer science favoured English, that's life)

Comment: Yup. Please use the sqlite3 library in Python, not that ConexxionDB. That way it's much easier to answer questions.